# Was he wearing a nose prosthetic in Multiverse of Madness?

Tags: marvel-cinematic-universe, make-up, dr-strange-multiverse-of-madness

In *Doctor Strange in the Multiverse of Madness*, a certain well-known comic character (not saying who here because the film's still new and he wasn't in the trailers) shows up with a rather prominent nose and a dark beard, making him look ambiguously Middle Eastern.  I looked it up and was surprised to learn that this was John Krasinski, better known to most viewers as Jim from *The Office.*

That really, really did not look like Jim, especially with the big nose!  Was he wearing a prosthetic nose for some reason, or was it just weird camera angles?

Comment: Sorry about the weird title tag; apparently the film's full name is longer than the tag size limit.

Comment: I VTCed this one since it's basically trivia and doesn't add to the understanding of the film or the character(s) or pretty much anything else; it's a one-off topic. Sorry @Mason but I tried finding a reason to keep it open.

Comment: well, Krasinski doesn't exactly have a 'small' nose...

Comment: There was one episode of The Office where they were talking about the employees' family history and someone mentioned that Jim was a distant relative of Richard Nixon who was known to have a big nose. Jim shrugged it off at first until he felt his own nose and showed a worried expression. But I think in the opening shot of his character, his nose did seem rather large. I was also taken aback. I think another reason was the camera angle as you said (the camera was facing upwards from Doctor Stange's perspective)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If the image on the right is accurate [I haven't seen the movie yet to know if this is a true screengrab from Dr Strange] then I'd say no.

[image]

I've always thought he has a rather 'intriguing' nose shape anyway, though I don't really know him from as far back as the Office, only from Jack Ryan & The Quiet Place.

[image]